# Java Running Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have written a basic code in java/eclipse like:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

But, I cannot run. When I click run, it shows me an error like:

```
"The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."
```

According to I look from forums and stackoverflow, they had told a solution for Android programs. They describe the solution from run configurations, when I enter there I cannot see Android tab. In run configurations it writes "Java Applet" and "Java Application" related with Java.

And my program isn't Android program. It's just "Hello World" program. What will I do? I really need help

Edit:
When I try from coding page; I can just see Run As --> Run Configurations and from dropdown I see Run As --> (none applicable)

Comment: This code is correct and can (will) run if used correctly. check the type of project you are working in. Check that your package statement is identical to the actual package it is in. ...

Comment: I opened java project and add Test.java file under it, It appears like there is no problem. :(

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps you followed (in detail) as to how you got this project you're trying to run?

Comment: I clicked right with mouse under "Package Explorer" and selected "New/Java Project" and named it "Test Project" then finished. After that, I clicked right to Test Project which is opened new, then added class "New/Class" and named it as "Test" and finished. A page came and I wrote the code which is above. However, I couldn't run :(

Comment: how did you try to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Without selecting any part of your program in editor, just right click and select Run As --> Java Application

(or)

Click inside your Editor, to make it active/focused, then use shortcut `Alt + Shift + X, J`.

Eclipse will automatically open a new Console window to your program output at the bottom of the editor.